# Java springJDBC has not have a method in class of CollectionFactory,

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

When I used jdbcTemplate's `queryForList(String sql)` method in junit, I got a question. Then I debugged and found that `CollectionFactory` does not find `createLinkedCaseInsensitiveMapIfPossible(int columnCount)`. It's terrible, because I write the test like spring-framework-reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need check you spring version.
The method `CollectionFactory#createLinkedCaseInsensitiveMapIfPossible` has been removed in spring 4,this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/e11cf5f061ef4c568c04f72ae535b0f409dbbebb#diff-e0f8c7b8fe5fb7290302641e81d33326L143) you can get more detail in github.
so,you have two solution:

- using this method,include spring3 to you dependency
- change spring-jdbc to version 4 from version 3.

Comment: thinks,I change spring-jdbc version to 4.3,the method is run normally

Comment: @tony you can using maven or gradle manage you library dependency.  ;)